# Bootstrap Toggle Plugin - Checkboxes Not Toggling When Using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) plugin to change my checkboxes into toggle switches. I'm also using AngularJS. When I set the checked value, it toggles fine. But when I don't, it does not toggle. You can see in the link to my results, that checkboxes are checked, but they are not toggling. Does anyone know why it's not binding using Angular?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-7 control-label">
        <span>Working Toggle </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input id="toggle-one" checked type="checkbox">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-7 control-label">
          <span>Color Review Check</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" ng-model="colorReview" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-7 control-label">
          <span>Type Review Check</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" ng-model="typeReview">
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=color-review" class="col-sm-7 control-label">
                <span>Color Review </span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="checkbox" id="color-review" class="pull-right" ng-model="colorReview" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type-review" class="col-sm-7 control-label">
                <span>Type Review </span>
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="checkbox"  id="type-review" class="pull-right" ng-model="typeReview">
            </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Set The Review Checkboxes To Toggle Switches
$('#color-review').bootstrapToggle();
$('#type-review').bootstrapToggle();
$('#toggle-one').bootstrapToggle();
```

**Results:** Here is a link to a picture of my results: 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AThH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at https://github.com/cgarvis/angular-toggle-switch?

```
    $scope.topics:[{"on":true,"offLabel":"Off","onLabel":"On"}];

    <div ng-repeat="t in topics"> 
        <toggle-switch model="t.switch.on" on-label="t.switch.onLabel" off-label="t.switch.offLabel" switched="doSomethingToggle(t, $index)"></toggle-switch>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I just added this, and it works easily.

I would prefer to use the bootstrap-toggle, but this is a workaround and I can style it. Thanks